# How to use list with class C++

Tags: c++, list, class, object, linked-list

i'm going to be crazy for this problem.
I'm trying to use list in c++. I can't use `<vector>` or `<list>`, cause my professor wants it in "pure" c++. (With class, in short..).
I can create list which has only an int field, for example:

```
    class List{
    private:
        struct node{
            int *data;
            node* next;
        };  
        typedef struct node* nodePtr;
        nodePtr head;
        nodePtr curr;
        nodePtr temp;

    public: 
    List();
    void AddNode(int addData);
    void deleteNode(int delData);
    void PrintList();
};
```

(this works, this isn't the entire code, but it works.)

The problem born now:
How could I create a list of objects, instead list of "int" data?

If i have, for example, to create a list of People, like an address book, how should I do?

I'm gonna be crazy, please help me. Thanks in advance.

(sorry for my bad english, i'm not that good :)

Answer (score 5):

The answer lies in template classes.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

```
<template class T>
class List{
    private:
        struct node{
            T *data;
            node* next;
        };  
        typedef struct node* nodePtr;
        nodePtr head;
        nodePtr curr;
        nodePtr temp;

    public: 
        List();
        void AddNode(T addData);
        void deleteNode(T delData);
        void PrintList();
};
```

Where you use list you now define the type you want to use

```
List<int> intList;
```

Comment: Mmm, thanks for the answer. When I try to use List<int> intList; it gives me this error:
undefined reference to "List<int>::List()".

Comment: You need to implement the template functions inside of a header file, and not in a separate source file.